# How does ASP.NET generate HTML?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have been handed an (OLD) ASP.NET website that I am working on that previously only worked on IE5-IE9. I managed to fix it so that it could work in IE11. (With the need of a serverside .NET hotfix).

Now I am also trying to get the website to work properly in Firefox and Chrome, but unfortunately the decapriated javascript doesn't work as intended and breaks some critical functionality entirely but is something I will work out later.

Right now I'm trying to get the style sheet to work properly cross-browser. I'd like to touch as little code as possible and not break anything else. From what I can see is that the page that is delivered to the browser is different per browser. See these screenshots.

Firefox
[image: Firefox]

Chrome
[image: Google Chrome]

IE11
[image: IE11]

As you can see the delivered code is different per browser. I am not sure if it is the browser itself doing this or ASP.NET. Is there a way to enforce a specific method? This is the code on the ASP.NET side. (Take note it is an ancient website.)

```
    <div id="menuDiv" runat="server">
      <asp:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menu" Visible="False">
        <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menu"></StaticMenuItemStyle>
      </asp:Menu>
    </div>
```

And this is the related CSS after trying to get it to display properly in firefox and IE11.

```
.menu a
{
padding-left: 40px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100px;
color: #0462a5;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
padding-top: 7px;
display: block;
text-align: left;
height: 20px;
color: #0462A5;
background-image: url(Images/web/menu.gif);
}
.menu a:hover
{
color: #000;
background-image: url(Images/web/menu_over.gif);
}
```

So again, how can I get these pages to return the same code (or same style) for every browser in ASP.NET?

Comment: I believe only updating your css will do the trick. You will not need to change the server side code. My advice to you is to make a css file and move all inline style to it. This way you will have all your css at one place with which you can play and update.

Comment: @Ratna That is what I am doing in the meanwhile. But I still find that chrome adding random <br>'s to be a disgusting thing.

Comment: try adding <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" SkipLinkText="">  skiplink is the key  in your menu

Comment: @Ratna Your suggestion makes this work perfectly in chrome but breaks all other browsers, haha... ha. I'm going to go and try out the browser definition files for now. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is perhaps your application is using Browser Definition Files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

These files would define what markup to send to which browser. I never much cared for the idea, they used to send table-based layouts instead of div-based ones to the earliest incarnations of Firefox as Microsoft considered it a "down-level" browser compared to IE *insert rolling-eyes emoticon here*

Have a look for those browser files and see if there are any mucking up markup for Chrome.

Comment: There are no custom browser definition files. But I'll see what I can do with this.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer. I fixed a great portion of my issue by using  "Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel";" for chrome.